If $\sin^2(3x)+\cos^2(2y)+\tan^2(4z)+\sin(3x)\cos(2y)+\sin(3x)\tan(4z)+\tan(4z)\cos(2y)\leq0$, where $x,y,z\in (0,\pi]$, then which is correct?

If $sin^2(3x)+\cos^2(2y)+\tan^2(4z)+\sin(3x)\cos(2y)+\sin(3x)\tan(4z)+\tan(4z)\cos(2y)\leq0$, where $x,y,z\in (0,\pi]$, then number of ordered triplets $(x,y,z)$ is/are

(a)$20$
(b) $24$
(c) $25$
(d) $32$
My solution
use the identitity $a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca=\dfrac{1}{2}\left((a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+a)^2\right)$
and obtained $(\sin3x+\cos2y)^2+(\cos2y+\tan4z)^2+(\tan4z+\sin3x)^2\leq0\implies$
$(\sin3x+\cos2y)=0 \;\&\;(\cos2y+\tan4z)=0 \;\&\;(\tan4z+\sin3x)=0 $
Hence $\sin3x=\cos2y=\tan4z=0$
Now how I do solve this to get total number of ordered triplets?

@JohnOmielan Fixed them

$\tan(4z) = 0 \iff \sin(4z) = 0$. Find the number of zeros of each function on that interval and look at all possible ways to combine them into a triple (this boils down to a combinatorical question)
